# What's wrong with PDO in other class?

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo

I'm just changing my website's MySQL to PDO, and I've got a strange problem when I tried to use PDO in an other class.

```
class Database {
private $pdo;

public function __construct() {
    $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=appdora;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
}
}

class doClass {

//Variables
private $db;

//PDO
public function __construct(Database $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

And the code is returns with: the following error:

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to doClass::__construct() must be an instance of Database, none given, called in .../index.php on line xx and defined in ../classes.php on line xx`

The code:

```
$do = new doClass();
if ($do->loginCheck()) { echo 'loginOk'; } else { 'loginError'; }
```

loginCheck() is a simle function that works without classes!

Could you help me, what's the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you inititing your `doClass`? Show that code.

Comment: Show the code where the error actually points to…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$do = new doClass();
```

You defined your `doClass` class to expect a parameter in the constructor:

```
public function __construct(Database $db)
```

So you need to supply that parameter of type `Database` to successfully construct the object.

For example, if you have a database object stored before somewhere inside a variable `$database`, you can simply pass it to the constructor of `doClass` like this:

```
$do = new doClass($database);
```

Comment: Could you let me know how to do that exactly?

Comment: Could you still help? If I try to make a PDO->query, it shows me the problem: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::query()`. I'm trying to access by: `$stmt = $this->db->query(...);`

Comment: Then you apparently didn’t define a `query` method within your `Database` class. You probably want to call the `query` method of the inner `PDO` object.