# PHP pdo inside class

Tags: php, pdo

Trying to do pdo statement inside another class, but I'm getting error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to products::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, none given, called in

if I drop PDO from constructor, I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
```

units.class.php:

```
class units {

  protected $dbh;

  public function __construct(PDO $dbh)
  {
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
  }
  public function getOneById($unit_id)
  {
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM units WHERE unit_id = :id");
    $sth->bindParam(':id', $unit_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $product = $sth->fetch();
    $sth->closeCursor();

    return $product;
  }
```

pdo.php:

```
try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO("....
```

These both are as required files in index.php and pdo.php is required BEFORE the class.

Comment: *Hm...* it might be a namespace issue here also. Try `public function __construct(\PDO $dbh)` and `$dbh = new \PDO("....` I could be wrong though but it does kinda smell like it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with PDO in other class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668062/whats-wrong-with-pdo-in-other-class)

Comment: I tried with \ but still I get `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to products::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, none given, called` from row where is __construct